How do I use SRGB with DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD?
I have a dx11 project and I'd like to change the color format from DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB.
The problem is that doing this while having DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD active results in 0x887a0001 (DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL) when trying to create the device&swapchain.
Using DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD instead of flip discard circumvents the issue, but I'd like to use the flip model somehow.
I found something that said that

you should provide the *_SRGB format only for the render target view, not the backbuffer itself.

but trying that out only resulted in CreateRenderTargetView crashing instead.
Is this possible? Am I missunderstanding something?
Edit: One minute after posting this I got this console output:

DXGI ERROR: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: Flip model swapchains (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL and DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD) only support the following Formats: (DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT, DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM), assuming the underlying Device does as well.

Does this mean it's impossible to use SRGB and Flip Discard?
Edit2: Here's my code for setting up my Device&Swapchain and RenderTargetView. The error I get is "E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.", which I can't figure out much from since the documentation for CreateRenderTargetView only states that it cannot be typeless or DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32, which I don't think the SRGB one is. Am I Setting up the D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC incorrectly?
bool GraphicsEngine::CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()
{
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc = {};
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    
    // replacing unorm with srgb in flip crashes. 
    //swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB; // cannot be used with flip
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = *myWindowHandle;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;

    //swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD; // we can switch to this if we increase buffer count >1
    
    UINT creationFlags = 0;

#if defined(REPORT_DX_WARNINGS)
    creationFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    HRESULT result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        creationFlags,
        nullptr,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &swapChainDesc,
        &mySwapChain,
        &myDevice,
        nullptr,
        &myContext);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool GraphicsEngine::CreateRenderTarget(HRESULT& aHresult)
{
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferTexture{};

    aHresult = mySwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&backBufferTexture));
    if (FAILED(aHresult))
    {
        return false;
    }

 // this is the line that causes the crash. originally I just sent nullptr instead of desc.
    D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC desc;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
    
    aHresult = myDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferTexture, &desc, &myBackBuffer);
    if (FAILED(aHresult)) // this is where we crash. the error we get is "E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid."
    {
        backBufferTexture->Release();
        return false;
    }

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    backBufferTexture->GetDesc(&textureDesc);
    backBufferTexture->Release();
    myBackBufferTextureHeight = textureDesc.Height;
    myBackBufferTextureWidth = textureDesc.Width;
    return true;
}


As you've found you can only use DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM_SRGB when creating the target view so you must concentrate your efforts on why CreateRenderTargetView is "crashing". Please post some reproducing code.

@SimonMourier Hi. I've updated my question with my code for setting up the Device&Swapchain as well as the CreateRenderTargetView, as well as the error message HRESULT is giving. Thank you for your time.

Errors like this can be generally diagnosed pretty easily if you enable the DirectX debug layer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps). In this case, it's because you didn't set D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC's ViewDimension. For example set it to D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D

It works now! I'll make sure to enable the debug layer as well. Thank you for your help!
